# Unity c# change opacity of the material

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, opacity

I have some code in which i generate two custom Materials by code like so:

```
var m = new Material(Shader.Find("Unlit/Transparent"));
m.SetTexture("_MainTex", (Texture)Resources.Load("data/"+Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("data/"+DatabaseData.local_photo_name)));
```

and the other material i generate like so:

```
var c = new Color(255, 0, 255, 1); //just an example color... 
var m = new Material(Shader.Find("Unlit/Color"));
m.SetColor("_Color", c);
```

no i want to change the opactity of these materials during runtime. (the materials have in the meantime been applied to the MeshRenderer component of a generated GameObject).

I tried to do this in the following way:

```
var RRenderer = InteractRecord.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
RRenderer.material.color = new Color(RRenderer.material.color.r, RRenderer.material.color.g, RRenderer.material.color.b, o);
```

But when i do this i get the following error:

> Material doesn't have a color property '_Color'
>   UnityEngine.Material:get_color()
>    DBRecord:SetRecordOpacity(Single, Boolean) (at Assets/scripts/DBRecord.cs:118)
>    Main:Update() (at Assets/scripts/Main.cs:66)

How would i go about doing this? And what am i currently doing wrong?

If anything is unclear let me know so i can clarify.

Comment: so you get that error when you use material.color?

Comment: yes because when i call the function that updates it, i get the error

Comment: Alright but not when you call `m.SetColor("_Color", c);`  Can you show us the full error?

Comment: yes exactly, i will update the question

Answer (score 0):

So after long searching and trying i figured out what the problem was.

I was creating a material with the following texture types:

> Unlit/Transparent

Even though the name even suggests it supports transparency it does so but only when you use a `.img` file that has transparency. It does NOT work when you want to change the opacity of the entire object.

> Unlit/Color

I had the same problem with this texture type, since its color property has a opacity value it does NOT affect the overall mesh.

So I check all the current shaders in unity all of them do not support the changing of the overall opacity of the 'mesh' / material.

So how to do it you may ask. Use the following shader of the legacy shaders in unity: `Shader.Find("Legacy Shaders/Transparent/Diffuse")` or any other shader in the Transparent category.

Hope this helps anyone!